# Int is not convertible to 'Range<Int>'

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`, which contains a `UIButton`(upVoteButtonPressed) and a `UILabel` (voteScoreLabel).

In order to get the numerical scores to show up in the labels of the UITableView, the array that contains that the number of votes is a String array, although its contents are in actuality integers.

The tag of the label has been set in the tableview controller to be the same as the `indexPath.row`. This lets me pick a particular item in the array.

However when I want to add a specific value, add 1 for example, I cannot because when I try to execute the following code I get the following error: `Int is not convertible to 'Range'`.

The code below is in my custom `UITableViewCell`. My goal is to pick out a particular value of the array, convert it to an integer and then add 1 to it. What does this mean and how can I fix it.

```
@IBAction func upVoteButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag]=groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag].toInt()
}
```

**Edit**

**The solution suggested in the comments to make the array type int, and then when putting into the tableview to convert to string has worked. Problem Solved.**

Comment: You can't do this. It's in probably the first or second chapter of the Swift book. Your array will be inferred as a String type array. You can't change that. Also, what is it you are trying to do here? It seems to be setting a value in the array back to the same value?

Comment: @Fogmeister I am trying to pick out a particular value of the array, then add 1 to it, but before I can do that I get the error `Int is not convertible to 'Range'`

Comment: So why not have an Int array then? That would make more sense.

Comment: @Fogmeister I would, but then I am using the array to fill the tableView labels. How would fill a label with an int value.

Comment: `label.text = "\(theIntValue)"` it's called string interpolation and is also explained in the Swift book. You should be storing the data in the format you need to use it in. Don't store it in the format you want to display it in. That's backwards.

Comment: How you declared `groupVote` ?

Comment: @MidhunMP The problem has been solved, see edit. Thanks

Comment: if the problem is solved please add it as an answer and accept it so the question will be complete on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the array type an int because the array is currently seen as a String type array and that is backwards and inefficient. Then when putting the array values into the `UITableView` use label.text = "(theIntValue)" to convert the int values into strings.